# How to display the upgrade progress when using Ansible Yum plug-in

Tags: ansible, yum, package-managers

I have an Ansible playbook which I use to configure repositories and upgrade packages. Since the package upgrade can take some time the task is hanging idle without providing any information.

How can I modify my playbook to provide an output when every time package upgrade completes successfully?

I have already tried to produce outputs using register variables but since it executes only after the upgrade task its not match with my requirement.

```
  - name: Apply All Latest Upgrades
    yum:
     name: '*'
     state: latest
    register: shell_result

  - debug:
     var: shell_result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't. It's running internally, you should just wait for it to complete.
However, you can try this: [How can I show progress for a long-running Ansible task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194021/how-can-i-show-progress-for-a-long-running-ansible-task)